# How to copy files from local folder to s3 bucket's root path without copying the folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-s3

I have a local folder with name `build`. I'm trying to copy all the files in that folder to an s3 bucket's root path.

I have `f1.txt`, `f2.txt`, `ff/f3.txt`, `ff/f4.txt` files in build folder. Notice the sub folders in the directory.

I tried executing the below command to copy the files

```
aws s3 cp build s3://$INTERNAL_DOCS_AWS_BUCKET --recursive
```

It's copying the whole folder and its contents to S3 bucket along with the folder.

The expected output in S3 bucket's root path is `all the files and subfolder mentioned above - f1.txt, f2.txt, ff/f3.txt, ff/f4.txt`

The actual output is - all the folders and subfolders with in `build` path in s3 bucket.

Comment: Are you sure that this is your real command, because the command is correct and it works as expected. Thus, its seems that your question does not show what you are actually doing.

Comment: Yes. The command is correct. But the actual output in s3 is `build/f1.txt`, `build/f2.txt`, `build/ff/f3.txt`, `build/ff/f4.txt`. I was looking for `f1.txt`, `f2.txt`, ... in s3 bucket.

Comment: I just run your command, and it works correctly. There is no `build` when objects are copied to s3.

Comment: Also what is `INTERNAL_DOCS_AWS_BUCKET`?

Comment: My bad. I was having permission issues and messed up things badly. Apologies.

Comment: You could try it by going into the `build` folder and then running `aws s3 cp . s3://destination --recursive`. That way, it is copying the contents of the current directory.